# Feynman Lectures Vol 1: Differentiation of Equation 13.4 a mathematical trick?

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

In the Feynman Lectures Vol 1 Chapter 13 ( http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_13.html ), he states the below.

*First we discuss the rate of change in three dimensions.  The kinetic energy in three dimensions is :*

$$T=\frac 1 2 m \left( v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2\right)$$

*When we differentiate with respect to time, we get three terrifying terms :*

$$\frac{dT}{dt}= m \left(v_x \frac {dv_x}{dt} + v_y \frac {dv_y}{dt} + v_z \frac {dv_z}{dt}\right)$$

Is he applying the product rule of differentiation to get the result in 13.4? If you just differentiate $\frac 1 2 m v_x^2$ wrt time, you should just be getting $m v_x$, right ?

Due to the product rule, now it is $m v_x \frac {dv_x}{dt}$. Certainly $mv_x$ cannot be same as $m v_x \frac {dv_x}{dt}$ , right ?  How is it right to apply the product rule or what am I missing here ?

Comment: I believe the differene is he is differentiating wrt time, not wrt the velocity in a particular direction (e.g, Vx). Does this clear it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that velocity is a function of time, so: $v_x=v_x(t)$.

According to the chain rule, let's differentiate the first component:

$T_x=\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2=\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2(t)$

$\dfrac{dT_x}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{dt}[\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2(t)]=\frac{1}{2}m\dfrac{d}{dt}[v_x^2(t)]=\frac{1}{2}m2v_x\dfrac{dv_x}{dt}=mv_x\dfrac{dv_x}{dt}$

The $y$ and $z$ components are obtained exactly in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the product rule, this is the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#The_chain_rule).
Consider $v_x$ as a function of the time. Then the function you want to differentiate is the compound function: $f(g(t))$, where $g(t)$ is your $v_x$  and $f(\xi) = \xi^2$. Apply the chain rule and you will get (13.4).

Comment: You could say that he differentiated the product $v_x\cdot v_x$ using the product rule?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the trick here is to multiply by $1$ or to be more exact - $\frac{dv_x}{dv_x}, \frac{dv_y}{dv_y}$ and $\frac{dv_z}{dv_z}$. So you get $\frac{v_x^2}{dv_x}.\frac{dv_x}{dt}$ and so on.